# Skorch: How to plot training and validation Accuracy

Tags: skorch

Is there a way how to plot a training and validation accuracy after we finished training with Skorch `net.fit(X_train, y_train)`. We can see the `train_loss`, `valid_loss`, and `valid_acc` but how about `train_acc`?
Thank you.

Comment: For a person not knowing skorch, I am not sure all people can understand what you did. I am pretty sure as a programmer it would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This was also answered in the [skorch issue tracker](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch/issues/798) but in short
you can simply add further scorer for the train accuracy:

```py
net = NeuralNetClassifier(
    # ...
    callbacks=[
        EpochScoring(scoring='accuracy', name='train_acc', on_train=True),
    ],
)
```

If you are working in a jupyter notebook you can simply run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(net.history[:, 'train_acc'])
```